# Jackson JSON library how to disable serialization of a given type

Tags: json, jackson

I am using JACKSON 1.6.3 version. I have one class which has a reference to itself and JACKSON serializer is failing with complains about "circular references". 
I would like to disable serialization of this class. This is a third party class and I can not add any annotation to it, I am wondering if there is a way to disable this type of object being serialized. I am ok if the serializer ignores the entire object.

Comment: have you tried `@JsonIgnore` on the property ?

Comment: Since this is a third party class, I can not use @JsonIgmore on it. This object is being referenced in my code from a HashMap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed the issue by creating a custom `JsonSerializer<T>` for the type and registered it with ObjectMapper

```
mapper = new ObjectMapper();
CustomSerializerFactory factory = new CustomSerializerFactory();
factory.addSpecificMapping(<Type to be handled>, <Custom Serializer>);
mapper.setSerializerFactory(factory);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done using `JacksonMixInAnnotations`.

See the accepted answer on [How can I tell jackson to ignore a property for which I don't have control over the source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421474/)