# How do I add a Jackson mixin to a reader and not to the objectmapper?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have an object that I would like to serialize with an attribute in one part of my program, but without in a different part.  I also have an ObjectMapper which is extensively customized that I use for both serializations.  My first inclination was to use a Mixin to tweak if the attribute is shown, but it seems that you can only put those on the ObjectMapper and not on a reader returned by the ObjectMapper.  Basically the code I would like to be able to write would look like the following.

```
ObjectMapper myMapper = new ObjectMapper(); // in reality there is a lot of customization
Foo foo = myMapper.reader().withMixin(Foo.class, FooMixin.class).readValue(jsonParser, Foo.class);
```

Comment: Which version of Jackson has withMixin method for ObjectReader ? I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct. You can not change mix-ins on-the-fly, however: since they are used for introspection of (de)serializers, and results (actual (de)serializers) are cached, they must be added as part of the initial configuration.
This is why neither `ObjectReader` nor `ObjectWriter` exposes methods to change mix-ins: they only allow changing of things that can be dynamically changed, on per-call basis.

But perhaps mix-ins are not the best way to do this: have you considered using [JSON Views](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews) instead? Active view in use can be changed separately for each (de)serialization.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can configure mixins for serialization or deserialization (or both of course):

```
objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(Rectangle.class, MixIn.class);
objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(Rectangle.class, MixIn.class);
```

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations