# Jackson serialization: how to ignore superclass properties

Tags: java, inheritance, serialization, jackson, superclass

I want to serialize a POJO class which is not under my control, but want to avoid serializing any of the properties which are coming from the superclass, and not from the final class. Example:

```
public class MyGeneratedRecord extends org.jooq.impl.UpdatableRecordImpl<...>,
    example.generated.tables.interfaces.IMyGenerated {
  public void setField1(...);
  public Integer getField1();

  public void setField2(...);
  public Integer getField2();
...
}
```

You can guess from the example that that this class is generated by JOOQ, and inherits from a complex base class UpdatableRecordImpl which also has some bean property-like methods, which cause problems during the serialization. Also, I have several similar classes, so it would be good to avoid duplicating the same solution for all of my generated POJOs.

I have found the following possible solutions so far:

- ignore the specific fields coming from superclass using mixin technique like this: [How can I tell jackson to ignore a property for which I don't have control over the source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421474/how-can-i-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-property-for-which-i-dont-have-control-over)

  The problem with this is that if the base class changes (e.g., a new getAnything() method appears in it), it can break my implementation.
- implement a custom serializer and handle the issue there. This seems a bit overkill to me.
- as incidentally I have an interface which describes exactly the properties I want to serialize, maybe I can mixin a @JsonSerialize(as=IMyGenerated.class) annotation...? Can I use this for my purpose?

But, from pure design point of view, the best would be to be able to tell jackson that I want to serialize only the final class' properties, and ignore all the inherited ones. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can register a custom [Jackson annotation intropector](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/AnnotationIntrospector) which would ignore all the properties that come from the certain super type. Here is an example:

```
public class JacksonIgnoreInherited {

    public static class Base {
        public final String field1;

        public Base(final String field1) {
            this.field1 = field1;
        }
    }

    public static class Bean extends Base {
        public final String field2;

        public Bean(final String field1, final String field2) {
            super(field1);
            this.field2 = field2;
        }
    }

    private static class IgnoreInheritedIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {
        @Override
        public boolean hasIgnoreMarker(final AnnotatedMember m) {
            return m.getDeclaringClass() == Base.class || super.hasIgnoreMarker(m);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new IgnoreInheritedIntrospector());
        final Bean bean = new Bean("a", "b");
        System.out.println(mapper
                        .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                        .writeValueAsString(bean));
    }

}
```

Output:

{
  "field2" : "b"
}

Comment: This solution worked for me.  Too ignore the complex JOOQ base classes, my ```hasIgnoreMarker``` implementation is ```return m.getDeclaringClass().getName().contains("org.jooq") || super.hasIgnoreMarker(m)```

Answer (score 22):

You can use this as well instead of unnecessary overrides

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "aFieldFromSuperClass"})
public class Child extends Base {
   private String id;       
   private String name; 
   private String category;
}
```

Comment: This is a better solution as final methods cannot be overriden.

Answer (score 17):

You can override the superclass' methods which you'd like to prevent from being output and annotate them with @JsonIgnore. The override shifts the control of property creation to the subclass while enabling its ability to filter it from the output.

For instance:

```
public class SomeClass {
  public void setField1(...);
  public Integer getField1();

  public void setField2(...);
  public Integer getField2();

  @Override
  @JsonIgnore
  public String superClassField1(...){
      return super.superClassField1();
  };

  @Override
  @JsonIgnore
  public String superClassField2(...){
      return super.superClassField2();
  };
...
}
```

Comment: To add to @AbhishekChatterjee's point, jackson uses the getters in the object to determine what to show, so it's only the getters that would need overridden.

Answer (score 3):

The good use of inheritance is that the child classes extend or add functionality. So the usual way is to serialize the data.

A workarround would be to use a Value Object (VO) or Data Transfer Object (DTO) with the fields you need to serialize. Steps:

- Create a VO class with the fields that should be serialized.
- Use BeanUtils.copyProperties(target VO, source data) to copy the properties
- Serialize the VO instance.

Comment: That would be a pure copy-paste in this case. The whole point using generated classes is to avoid duplication of my schema information (fields, types etc.). Ideally, a field's name shall be typed exactly once -- in my SQL schema (or in a hand-written POJO in case of ORM). So far, it is more-or-less true in my design, and I do not want to break that.

Comment: Otherwise, you need to redefine the field on the child class and mark it as "not serializable".

Comment: @Ferenc: You can have jOOQ generate all those POJOs / VOs / DTOs for you: http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-pojos/

Comment: Yes, that is another possible solution -- I use the POJOs already, so a simple .into(MyGenerated.class) on the select method could also do it. Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

Add the following annotation in your Base Class :

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
```