# Jackson ignore all properties of superclass from external library

Tags: java, json, inheritance, jackson

I am developing using an ORM where I extend a base orm class to create tables.

For example:

```
public class Person extends DbItem {
    @JsonIgnore
    private String index;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;
}
```

Problem is that when I use ObjectMapper to serialize, it tries to serialize the members of the DbItem class. Is there any simple way to prevent this? For example with an annotation.

I had a look at a similar problem [Jackson serialization: how to ignore superclass properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945580/jackson-serialization-how-to-ignore-superclass-properties) but I was hoping it could be done simpler, and I'm not sure if I could do it as I can't change the superclass since it is in an external library.

Comment: Have you tried playing with `@JsonIgnoreProperties` at class level, combined with `@JsonProperty` for the `Person` props you need? Not sure it's applicable tbh, just a thought.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

## You can use a [Mix-in](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations) or [`@JsonIgnoreProperties`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.2/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonIgnoreProperties.html)

For the purposes of these examples, the base ORM class and extension are assumed to be:

```
public class DbItem {
    public String dbPropertyA;
    public String dbPropertyB;
}
```

and

```
public class Person extends DbItem {
    public String index;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
}
```

respectively.

## Using a Mix-in

A Mix-in is an abstraction of the de/serialization instructions that Jackson understands from an object itself. It is a way to customize de/serialization of 3rd party classes. In order to define a Mix-in, an abstract class must be created and registered with the `ObjectMapper`.

#### Example Mix-in Definition

```
public abstract class PersonMixIn {
    @JsonIgnore public String dbPropertyA;
    @JsonIgnore public String dbPropertyB;
    @JsonIgnore public String index;
}
```

#### Registering the Mix-in

```
@Test
public void serializePersonWithMixIn() throws JsonProcessingException {
    // set up test data including parent properties
    Person person = makeFakePerson();

    // register the mix in
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper()
            .addMixIn(Person.class, PersonMixIn.class);

    // translate object to JSON string using Jackson
    String json = om.writeValueAsString(person);

    assertFalse(json.contains("dbPropertyA"));
    assertFalse(json.contains("dbPropertyB"));
    assertFalse(json.contains("index"));
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

### `@JsonIgnoreProperties`

If you want to avoid creating a class and configuring the `ObjectMapper`, the `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation can be utilized. Simply annotate the class you are serializing and list the properties to exclude.

#### Example Serializable Object

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"index", "dbPropertyA", "dbPropertyB"})
public class Person extends DbItem {
    public String index;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
}
```

#### See It In Action

```
@Test
public void serializePersonWithIgnorePropertiesAnnotation() throws JsonProcessingException {
    // set up test data including parent properties
    Person person = makeFakePerson();

    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

    // translate object to JSON string using Jackson
    String json = om.writeValueAsString(person);

    assertFalse(json.contains("dbPropertyA"));
    assertFalse(json.contains("dbPropertyB"));
    assertFalse(json.contains("index"));
    System.out.println(json);
}
```

Comment: So I would have to include all members of the base class in the PersonMixIn then right? I was hoping for something simpler but I guess it's a way to go. Problem is that whenever the base class changes, it would require maintenance on the code

Comment: @simernes there is also a `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation that can be used on the child class. Same thing applies, you need to list all of the properties that you want to exclude. Since the base class is a 3rd party library, I would assume you're not updating the version of the lib in your project frequently? I'd recommend writing a unit test to confirm the desired serialization of the `Person` object so that you know when the base has changed and the Mix-in needs updating.

Comment: I'll update the answer to include an example of both.

Comment: This even works for overriding `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotations in super classes. Great find!

Answer (score 0):

You want to do custom field level serialization. This will be a bit more work to maintain your code base, but is by far the simplest solution. See [Jackson JSON custom serialization for certain fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12046786/jackson-json-custom-serialization-for-certain-fields) for implementation details.