# Annotation for binding a json field to a field in POJO with a different name

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot

Java class (used as a Data Transfer Object):

class Resource also has a field named `id` with a different type along with its getter and setter, hence the syntax error.

```
class A extends Resource
{
   private int id;

   public int getId() { return id; }   // syntax error as getId() function already exists in Resource
   public void setId(int id) { this.id = id; }
}
```

Since the above class is a DTO, a JSON response (with field `id`) will be mapped to it, and getId() cannot be used, I want to change the field to `_id_` and change getter and setter correspondingly, and mark it with an annotation saying bind this to `id` field.

Note: I'm using spring boot. I tried using @JsonProperty annotation but that didn't work. Is there an annotation for doing this in spring?

Comment: @JsonProperty("_id_") above doesn't works?

Comment: No it does not work. It still looks for a field named "id"

Comment: When you say it doesn't work... is some exception being thrown? Can you provide some insight on how it isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

Googled and found this question: [Jackson serialization: how to ignore superclass properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945580/jackson-serialization-how-to-ignore-superclass-properties). Adapted it for your problem.

```
public class A extends B {
    private int id;

    public A(int id) {
        super.setId("id" + id);
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    @JsonProperty("_id_")
    public String getId() {
        return super.getId();
    }

    @Override
    @JsonProperty("_id_")
    public void setId(String id) {
        super.setId(id);
    }

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public int getIntId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public void setIntId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public class B {
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Tested it with this:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public A test() {
        return new A(1);
    }
}
```

And the output was:

```
{
  "_id_": "id1",
  "id": 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public A extends Resource {
    private int id;

    @JsonProperty("_id")
    public int getId() {
      return id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
    }
}
```

the method names should be different, so jackson parses it as different fields, not as one field.

Comment: @JsonProperty isn't working as I mentioned. Is it supposed to work with Spring MVC or Spring Boot?

Comment: Also, I cannot have a getId() function as there is a function getId() in the super class with a different return type

Comment: Or just bind two different getters/setters pair to one variable as commented by one on the link i gave in previous comment

Comment: They have used the same thing. @JsonProperty. That is not working for me

Comment: Then you need to find answer as to why it is not working, not what you could use for this kind of problems.