# Dropwizard deserialising custom exception as JSON?

Tags: java, jackson, jetty, dropwizard, exceptionmapper

I have created a new exception class in my Dropwizard service that extends BadRequestException.

```
public class CustomBadRequestException extends BadRequestException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<ValidationFailureDto> validationFailures;

    public CustomBadRequestException() {
        super();
    }

    public CustomBadRequestException(final List<ValidationFailureDto> validationFailures) {
        super();
        this.validationFailures = validationFailures;
    }

    @ApiModelProperty(value = "List of validationFailures")
    public List<ValidationFailureDto> getValidationFailures() {
        return validationFailures;
    }
}
```

When I throw that exception at first I was only getting back the deserialised BadRequestException, minus the additional property (validationFailures)

```
{
code: "400",
message: "Bad request"
}
```

This is because Dropwizard's internals have a default exception mapper that allows Jetty/Jackson  to understand domain exceptions and how to send the appropriate HTTP response.

To overcome this you can implement your own ExceptionMapper class and register it with Dropwizard.

```
public class CustomBadRequestExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<SamplePackOrderBadRequestException> {

/**
 * Allows jackson to deserialise custom exceptions and its properties to JSON response
 *
 * @param exception exception
 * @return response object
 */
@Override
public Response toResponse(final SamplePackOrderBadRequestException exception) {

    if (exception instanceof SamplePackOrderBadRequestException) {

        SamplePackOrderBadRequestException samplePackOrderBadRequestException
                = (SamplePackOrderBadRequestException) exception;
        return Response
                .status(400)
                .entity(samplePackOrderBadRequestException)
                .build();
    }
    return Response.status(400).build();
}
}
```

However this issue with this is that it deserializes super (Throwable), so you get every single inherited property added in the response which I do not want.

To combat this I tried adding Jackson annotations like so:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = "stackTrace")
```

This is not an optimal solution as there are several properties other than stackTrace that I will need to ignore.

So to summarise, how can I get Dropwizard to properly deserialize my CustomException class without all the additional clutter that I do not need?

Comment: You can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945580/jackson-serialization-how-to-ignore-superclass-properties You'll have to be careful though about how you use that. The Objectmapper provided by DW is shared, so make sure your other objects don't suffer from this :) I think it would be easier to just create a wrapper object that you use instead

Comment: Dropwizard is actually using the approach recommended in the answer below. They use a [custom ErrorMessage Java bean](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-jersey/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/jersey/errors/ErrorMessage.java) and added `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)` annotation :). And this is how [their ExceptionLoggingMapper}(https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-jersey/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/jersey/errors/LoggingExceptionMapper.java) is looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easier option is to transform exception to a `Error` bean and return it as shown below.

```
public class CustomBadRequestExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<SamplePackOrderBadRequestException> {


@Override
public Response toResponse(final SamplePackOrderBadRequestException exception) {

    if (exception instanceof SamplePackOrderBadRequestException) {

        SamplePackOrderBadRequestException ex
            = (SamplePackOrderBadRequestException) exception;
         return Response
            .status(400)
            .entity(new ErrorBean(400,ex.getMessage,ex.getgetValidationFailures()))
            .build();
    }
    return Response.status(400).build();
}
}
```

And ErrorBean.java

```
    public static class ErrorBean{
    private int code;
    private String message;
    private List<ValidationFailureDto> failures;
    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }
    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
    public List<ValidationFailureDto> getFailures() {
        return failures;
    }
    public void setFailures(List<ValidationFailureDto> failures) {
        this.failures = failures;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could mention that this is how Dropwizard is doing it itself. See my comment under the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43231802/dropwizard-deserialising-custom-exception-as-json#comment73584583_43231802