# Hibernate Criteria API disable Fetching

Tags: database, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have entity say Entity1  which has 1 to many relationship with Entity 2 & Entity 3.

Can I use criteria API so that conditionally when i fetch Entity 1 I fetch on Entity 2 but dont fetch Entity 3

Comment: How did you annotate the relationships? FetchType.EAGER?

Comment: No its lazy.. But i dont want it to be fetched at all

Comment: if it lazys and you do not use fetch joins, what happens?

Comment: When I try to convert the entity to JSON it fetches and prints them. I mean internally Spring does it

Comment: I do not know spring, but what about using XmlTransient or JSonIgnore annotations on the relationships?

Comment: But I need it to be conditional.. Not always

Comment: Are your version of spring using jackson? then see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421474/how-can-i-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-property-for-which-i-dont-have-control-over

Answer (score 0):

If it's happening while you convert to JSON — I would use `SELECT NEW` queries with approrpiate DTO constructor. This way you'll get as much flexibility as you need.