# How to Ignore fields when using JSONArray in Java

Tags: java, json

I want to ignore some fields when using JSONArray:

```
public class Person {
private Integer id;
private String name;
//field to ignore in json
private Account account;
...
```

Here I use JSONArray:

```
public static JSONArray listToJson(List objects) throws JSONException {
    return new JSONArray(objects);

}
```

Comment: Please refer link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7421474/how-can-i-tell-jackson-to-ignore-a-property-for-which-i-dont-have-control-over

Comment: I tried @JsonIgnore already, it's not working for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `transient` key word for it.

```
private transient Account account;
```

> Variables may be marked transient to indicate that they are not part of the persistent state of an object.

Comment: Hmm, what Json library are you using?